# Creating a buffer around a geographic point and then checking whether a list of coordinates is inside that buffer?

Tags: r, maps, gis

I have the following puzzle regarding spatial data in R:

I have a dataset with street segments (with their respective starting and ending coordinates). I want to create a buffer of X meters around these points and then check whether a list of lat/lon points is within that buffer. Is there a way to do this in R?

I'm able to map the points and map the buffers using a combination of various packages: maptools, ggmap, rgdal, sp, and rgeos. But this procedure seems to only map the points and the buffers without allowing me to then check if the other coordinates I have are within the buffers. Ideally, I'd like to produce a vector of 1s and 0s describing whether the list of lat/lon points are within the buffer around the street segments.

Any ideas?

This is the code I've been using, but I get all missing values (and I know this shouldn't be the case). I've also tried using the gContains function from rgeos but it crashed R.

```
#Load shapefile in R and transform to appropriate CRS
shp <- readOGR(dsn="/Users/Maps/shapes", layer="shp")
shp_transf <- spTransform(shp_transf, CRS( "+init=epsg:21897" ))

#Create buffer around polygons
shp_buff <- gBuffer(shp_transf, width=40, byid=TRUE, quadsegs=10)

#Make my dataframe of lat/lon points into same projection as buffers
points <- SpatialPoints(points,proj4string=CRS(proj4string(shp_buff)))

#Use over function from SP pacakge
result <- as.integer(over(points, shp_buff)$OBJECTID)
```

Comment: What happens when you just run `result <- over(points, shp_buff)`?

Comment: It creates an empty dataframe of the same dimensions as shp_buff

Comment: When you are declaring your `points` object, are the coordinates in the data frame already in the epsg:21897 CRS? The wording of the comment above that line kind of sounds like you are trying to transform them. Also, what happens when you run `plot(shp_buff)` then `plot(points, add=T)`?

Comment: Hi Jacob - I run that to make sure that the `points` vector are in the same projection as the shapefile `shp`. When running `plot(shp_buff)` it creates a plot of the buffers but running `plot(points, add=T)` creates a null value.

Comment: My question is, are the points originally in the coordinate system you are defining them with or are you expecting them to be transformed by the SparialPoints function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the `over()` function wasn't working before because the shapefile with the buffers and the list of GPS coordinates were in a different CRS. I fixed it this way:

`shp <- spTransform(shp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
proj4string(points) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")`

Then, you run the `over()` function and it'll give you the number of times each point is in each buffer area:

`x <- over(points, shp)
table(x$ID)`

`181    304`

`118     8`

So a particular GPS pulse came from segment ID 181 a total of 118 times and from segment ID 304 a total of 8 times.